# jQuery Toggle and Hover functionaility

Tags: jquery, hover, toggle, bind

So I have an element that toggles between two background colours when clicked.  But when the element is not selected, I want the background colour to change (and revert) on a hover.  I've tried using the .on('hover') and .off('hover') within the toggle, but only the .off() seems to work.

```
$('.element').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css('background', '#e7f1f5');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css('background', '#fff');
  }
);

$('.element').toggle(
  function( select ) {
    select.preventDefault();
    $(this).off('hover');
    $(this).css('background', '#f6f6f6');
    other.code();
  },
  function( unselect ) {
    unselect.preventDefault();
    $(this).on('hover');
    $(this).css('background', '#fff');
    other.code();
  }
);
```

I toggle 'on', the 'hover' event no longer triggers (as desired).
When I toggle 'off', the 'hover' event still does not trigger.

I'm fairly new to jQuery and StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if this question is trivial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use css:

```
.element{
   background-color:#FFF;
}
.element.hover{
   background-color:#e7f1f5;
}
```

instead of `$(this).off('hover');` do:

```
$(this).addClass('hover');
```

instead of `$(this).on('hover');` do:

```
$(this).removeClass('hover');
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work.  After the element is toggled 'on', the hover event should not work.  This doesn't seem to address that issue.

Comment: @MichaelChoi try `$(this).hover();` instead of `on`

Comment: I didn't even think of changing hover in css.  Thanks!